# Dynamic Table in React doesn't rerender if the new value is under the same row and header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, html-table, render

This is my table that's being returned from my functional component

```
<table class="table"> {/* Consonant Table */}
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="2">---</th>
                        {headersPOA.map( e => //headers for POA
                            <th colSpan="2">{e}</th>)}
                    </tr>

                    {headersMOA.map(c => //headers for MOA
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="2">{c}</th>
                        {addRowSpaces(getRowContent(c)).map(d => //row content with spaces
                            <td align= "center" width= "60px" height= "40px">
                                <button>{d.symbol}</button>
                            </td> 
                            )}
                    </tr>)}
                </table>
```

These are the functions I use to fill it in:

```
    const [headersPOA, setHeadersPOA] = useState([]);
    const [headersMOA, setHeadersMOA] = useState([]);

    function getRowContent(moaToTest){// get consonant table row contents
        let row = Object.values(phonemes)
            .filter(phoneme => phoneme.moa === moaToTest)
        return row;
    }

    function addRowSpaces(rowPhonemes) {// add spacing to consonant table rows
        let result = []

        headersPOA.forEach(element => { //check what phoneme to put in each column
            var foundUnvoiced = false; //no unvoiced phonemes fit in this column yet
            var foundVoiced = false; //no voiced phonemes fit in this column yet
            var phonemesInColumn = [] //both voiced and unvoiced phonemes in that column
            for(var i = 0; i < rowPhonemes.length; i++) { //check if any of the phoneme in that row matches the column
                if(rowPhonemes[i].poa === element) { //the phoneme has that poa
                    phonemesInColumn.push(rowPhonemes[i])
                    rowPhonemes.splice(i, 1)
                }
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < phonemesInColumn.length; i++){//check if unvoiced of unvoiced
                if(phonemesInColumn[i].sol === "Unvoiced"){
                    result.push(phonemesInColumn[i])
                    phonemesInColumn.splice(i, 1)
                    foundUnvoiced = true
                }
            }
            if(foundUnvoiced === false){
                result.push("")
            }

            for(var i = 0; i < phonemesInColumn.length; i++){//check if voiced of unvoiced
                if(phonemesInColumn[i].sol === "Voiced"){
                    result.push(phonemesInColumn[i])
                    phonemesInColumn.splice(i, 1)
                    foundVoiced = true
                }
            }
            if(foundVoiced === false){
                result.push("")
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    function getConsonantHeadersPOA() {//get unique POA
        let uniquePOA = [...new Set(Object.values(phonemes)
            .filter(phoneme => phoneme.type === "C")
            .map(phoneme => (phoneme.poa)))];

        return uniquePOA;
    }

    function getConsonantHeadersMOA() {//get unique MOA
        let uniqueMOA = [...new Set(Object.values(phonemes)
            .filter(phoneme => phoneme.type === "C")
            .map(phoneme => (phoneme.moa)))];

        return uniqueMOA;
    }
```

This is a picture of my table. When I submit a new value it is added correctly but the table won't update if the new phoneme is under the same header and in the same row as another one. If I added one that was Voiced(on the right), Palatal, Plosive, it would be added but not to the table because it's the C is in the same place but Unvoiced(on the left). Does anyone know why this is happening?
[My table]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hi8I.png

Comment: Add  a unique 'key' attribute to <td> Something like <td align= "center" key={uniqueid} width= "60px" height= "40px">
                                <button>{d.symbol}</button>
                            </td>

Comment: That didn't work for me. What does the key do to make it rerender? And do you know why the rendering would depend on where in the table there's new data?

Comment: create a Minimal, Reproducible Example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
You can use https://codesandbox.io/ to create minimal example.

Comment: https://gkv6q.csb.app/ I stripped out everything not involved in the issue and I renamed the headers to make it a bit simpler to talk about. C is Manner 1, Place 5, Left so if I add T in Manner 1, Place 5, Right it will be added to the list below but not on the table. It will work if I add one anywhere that doesn't have a Symbol in the same place and manner. It won't show up the inverse either. If I try to add one in manner 1 place 1 left it won't add because B is next to it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/loving-waterfall-gkv6q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark I've never used codesandbox for this so I'm not sure if I sent that correctly.

Comment: I've used console.log() and from what I can tell getRowContentC() is producing the correct result but once it's called by addRowSpacesC() the parameter isn't the result of getRowContentC() if the new sound has the same place and manner

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had this line rowPhonemes.splice(i, 1) which I had needed for a previous version but after the changes I made it was removing the second item it read that shared the same Place and Manner.

Comment: Good to hear! I also thought getRowContentC() wasn't returning correct results.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZSSEP9TKQSiJPvtL7

https://photos.app.goo.gl/8wnVGWpTyu41Rg6b6